# C# + linq(concat) rewrite to java

Tags: java, c#, linq, java-8

I have a code example in C# (with linq) but am trying to translate this to java code (java 8). But am getting very confused about what happens. Also i am not able to reproduce the same result in java as from the c# code.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNeighborNodes(Node v)
{
    var q = (from edge in this.Edges
        where edge.Start == v
        select edge.End)
        .Concat(from edge in this.Edges
            where edge.End == v
            select edge.Start);
    return q;
}
```

I get very confused by the Concat part. Can anyone explain what happens and how to reproduce this in java ?

Comment: Are you using JDBC plainly or JPA?

Comment: in both java and the c# code the edges are a list of Edge objects

Comment: The expression selects out of all Edges the Nodes `edge.End` where `edge.Start == v` and also all the Nodes `Edge.Start` where `edge.End == v`. Concat just concatenates both select's resulting IEnumerables to a single IEnumerable.

Comment: `Concat` method just concats two IEnumerable sequences into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = (from edge in this.Edges
    where edge.Start == v
    select edge.End)
    .Concat(from edge in this.Edges
        where edge.End == v
        select edge.Start);
```

this is same as

```
var q = 
  ctx.Edges.Where(o => o.Start == v).Select(o => o.End).Union(
  ctx.Edges.Where(o => o.End == v).Select(o => o.Start)).ToList();
```

and this would be

```
Stream<Node> q = Stream.concat(
  this.getEdges().stream().filter(o-> o.getStart() == v).map(o-> o.getEnd()),
  this.getEdges().stream().filter(o-> o.getEnd() == v).map(o-> o.getStart())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, use the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for concat between 2 lists.

```
List<Edge> result1 = ....;
List<Edge> result2 = ....;

//Java 8 and higher
List<Edge> q = Stream.concat(result1.stream(), result2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, if not using Java 8 or higher

```
List<Edge> q = new ArrayList<>();
q.addAll(result1);
q.addAll(result2);
```

I take the assumption that you will be returning a `List<Edge>` (if using an ORM model). Alternatively, if using JDBC, use a SQL query with a `UNION` joins and return a unionized result set, thus preventing you from doing contatenations on code, particularly if your dataset is huge.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem isn't the `Concat`. This is only needed in the C# code because it isn't really well coded.
You can do the same in Java like so (sorry, my java is a little bit rusty, but I think you get the idea):

```
ArrayList<Edge> q = new ArrayList<Edge>();

for (Edge edge : this.getEdges())
{
    if (edge.getStart() == v)
    {
        q.add(edge.getEnd());
    }
    else if (edge.getEnd() == v)
    {
        q.add(edge.getStart());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the Java equivalent code will be something like this:

```
Stream<Node> q = Stream.concat(
this.getEdges()
.stream()
.filter(edge -> edge.getStart() == v)
.map(edge -> edge.getEnd()),

this.getEdges()
.stream()
.filter(edge -> edge.getEnd() == v)
.map(edge -> edge.getStart())
);
```